# "Point-wise" value of Bochner integral of $L^2$ functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $T:L^2(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R})$ be a linear operator and $\phi:[a,b]\rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R})$ be a parameterised family of $L^2$ functions. I sometimes see an integral (which seems to be called a Bochner integral) like

$$\int_a^b T\phi(t)\,dt,$$

which is supposed to give an element of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, call it $f$.

**Question:** How does one interpret $f$ as an actual function (up to a set of measure $0$)? For instance, it is possible to make a statement like: the point-wise value of $f$ at $x$ (up to a set of measure $0$) is the same as the value

$$\int_a^b (T\phi(t))(x)\,dt\in\mathbb{R}$$

where $T\phi(t)(x)$ is the value at $x$ of some representative of $T\phi(t)\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$? I'm not sure if the last question makes sense in general, but it certainly should if $\phi(t)$ was point-wise well-defined, for example if for all $t$ we have $\phi(t)\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})\subseteq L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: You can interpret Bochner integrals on Hilbert spaces via the Riesz representation theorem, as follows. If $(X,\mu)$ is a finite measure space, $H$ is a Hilbert space, and $f:X \to H$ is bounded/measurable, then we define $\int_X f d\mu$ to be the unique element $k \in H$ such that for every $h \in H$ we have that $$\langle h,k \rangle = \int_X \langle h,f(x) \rangle \mu(dx).$$Such an element $k$ is guaranteed to exist by the Riesz representation theorem since $h \mapsto \int_X \langle h,f(x) \rangle \mu(dx)$ gives a bounded linear functional on $H$.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! Do you know of a reference for this?

Comment: Regarding your question about pointwise evaluation, let us consider the special case that $H=L^2(\Bbb R)$. In this case, we can consider $f:X \to H$ to be a jointly measurable function $f(x)(y)=f(x,y)$, with $x \in X$ and $y \in \Bbb R$. Then the above expression from my previous comment basically reduces to (after using Fubini's theorem) the equality that $$\bigg\langle h, \int_X f\;d\mu \bigg\rangle = \int_{\Bbb R} \bigg[ \int_X f(x,y) \mu(dx) \bigg] h(y) dy$$ from which (by arbitrarity of $h$) you can deduce the $y$-a.e. equality: $$\bigg( \int_X fd\mu \bigg)(y) = \int_X f(x,y)\mu(dx)$$

Comment: I don't know any good reference, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can interpret the Bochner integral in this case as pointwise integration. The Bochner integral of a function $f$ with values in a Banach space $X$ with respect to some measure $\mu$ satisfies $\int pf~\mathrm d\mu=p\int f~\mathrm d\mu$ for every continuous linear functional $p$.

Comment: I see. If $X$ = $L^2$, what would $p$ be, since evaluation at a point is not well-defined?

Comment: The point is that you could use these linear functionals (not one of them) to detect failure of almost everywhere pointwise convergence. If there were an  exceptional set of positive measure, there would be an exceptional set of finite positive measure on which the pointwise integral would be too large or too small (but not both). You can construct the appropriate linear functional from tis indicator function.