# Sanity check: bounded linear map commutes with Bochner integral

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

I wanted to check whether the following claim and proof are valid. Let $X,Y$ be separable Hilbert spaces, $(S,\mu)$ a measure space, and $A:X\rightarrow Y$ a bounded linear map. Let $f:S\rightarrow X$ be a Bochner-integrable function, so that the Bochner integral

$$\int_S f(s)\,d\mu(s)$$

gives an element of $X$. Suppose also that

$$\int_S Af(s)\,d\mu(s)$$

exists as an element of $Y$.

**Claim:**

$$A\int_S f(s)\,d\mu(s) = \int_S Af(s)\,d\mu(s).$$

**Proof:** Observe that by the answer to ["Point-wise" value of Bochner integral of $L^2$ functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2536171/point-wise-value-of-bochner-integral-of-l2-functions), the above is true if $A$ were a bounded linear map $X\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$. Let $\{v_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a Hilbert basis for $Y$ and $p_i$ be the bounded linear functional $\langle\,\cdot\,,v_i\rangle$ for each $i\in I$. Then applying the previous observation to $p_i\circ A:X\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ and $p_i:Y\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ gives

$$p_i\circ A\int_S f(s)\,d\mu(s) = \int_S p_i\circ Af(s)\,d\mu(s) = p_i\int_S Af(s)\,d\mu(s)$$

for all $i\in I$. The claim follows by non-degeneracy of the inner product on $Y$.

Comment: I cannot really tell if your proof is correct or not, by the way, but I feel like Bochner integral is a special case of the integral defined by the way that Dinculeanu does, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is taken from Vector Measure, by Nicolae Dinculeanu, page 123:

Let $m$ be a scalar measure and $U:E\rightarrow F$ a continuous linear operation. If $f\in\mathcal{L}_{E}^{1}(m)$, then $U\circ f\in\mathcal{L}_{F}^{1}(m)$ and

\begin{align*}
\int U\circ fdm=U\left(\int fdm\right).
\end{align*}

The sketch of the proof goes like this: First argue with simple functions, for general case, since Dinculeanu defines the integral to be the $\mathcal{L}_{E}^{1}$-Cauchy sequence of simple functions, so the claim goes through.

Answer (score 2):

This question is answered in the affirmative on p. 427 of the book *Infinite Dimensional Analysis: A Hitchhiker's Guide* by Aliprantis and Border.

I believe user284331's answer also works.